# How do a write a comment within a SpEL expression?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, spring-el, comments

I have a Spring Expression Language (SpEL) expression within a Thymeleaf attribute. It's getting a little long, and part of it may not be clear to other developers, so I want to include a comment within it.

I'm looking to do something like:

```
T(example.long.package.MyClass).someMethod("abc" /* Explain why value is "abc" here */ )
```

Except that the `/*...*/` syntax doesn't work, and the expression is of course more complicated. This is just an example; I'm looking for a general way of having comments within complicated SpEL expressions. I don't see any references to commenting within the [Spring documentation chapter on SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html).

I can work around it for now by having a Thymeleaf/HTML comment near the expression, I just would like to be able to have comments within expressions as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to include a `Javadoc` for `example.long.package.MyClass.someMethod`.
Include comments for business methods into the view is not good practice (IMHO)

Comment: I agree that it's a bit odd, but here I'm not trying to document what the parameter means. I'm trying to document why this particular call site is passing a value that might seem like an odd choice for that parameter. Odd enough that I thought it worthwhile to add a comment. Because yes, having something "important" in the view layer is indeed odd.